# Printing list from an array through a button click/function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, button, appendchild

So I added a button that creates an unordered list  from an array (var list_content = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Papaya"];), with each array item being shown as a list item ***li*** element. I also appended the list to a div target.

```
var question4 = document.querySelector('#btn4');
question4.addEventListener('click', switch4);

var listContent = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Papaya'];

function switch4() {
    var newElement = document.createElement('Li');
    div4.appendChild(newElement);
    for (var i = 0; i < listContent.length; i++) {
        newElement.textContent += listContent[i];
    }
}
```

However when I click the button on my webpage, ***'AppleBananaOrangeMangoPapaya'*** is printed after every button click.

When I change the for loop to be:

```
 newElement.textContent = listContent[i];
```

Then all that prints is ***'Papaya'***.

I need the button to print 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango', and 'Papaya' seperately after each button click (so 'Apple' on the first click, 'Banana' on the second click and so forth) but I am stuck on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening as you are looping through full `listContent` array on each button click. You can resolve it by adding a `index` variable with default value 0 and only adding the `listContent` element at that index and using post-increment `++` it will keep adding the next element on each click like:

```js
var div4 = document.querySelector('#div4');
var question4 = document.querySelector('#btn4');
var index = 0;
question4.addEventListener('click', switch4);

var listContent = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Papaya'];

function switch4() {
  var newElement = document.createElement('Li');
  newElement.textContent = listContent[index++];
  div4.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

```css
#div4 {margin-top:10px;}
li {margin: 0 10px;padding: 5px 0;}
```

```html
<button id="btn4">Click Me</button>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
var question4 = document.querySelector('#btn4');
question4.addEventListener('click', switch4);

var listContent = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Papaya'];

i = 0;
function switch4() {
    var newElement = document.createElement('Li');
    div4.appendChild(newElement);
    newElement.textContent = listContent[i];
    i++;
    if (i >= listContent.length){
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

you are looping through the array and appending all items in array to same `li` you created.
So each time you click, all elements in array are merged and added as a new `li` element

```
for (var i = 0; i < listContent.length; i++) {
        newElement.textContent += listContent[i]; // --> issue
    }
```

### Solution

If you want to add an element on each click, you should add a variable to track uptill which element you have added to list.

```
let startIndex = 0;
function switch4() {

    if(startIndex < listContent.length){
       let newElement = document.createElement('Li');
       div4.appendChild(newElement);
       newElement.textContent = listContent[startIndex];
      startIndex++;

    }

}
```